# NLog - ignore certain messages using filters

Tags: nlog

I want to NLog to ignore certain messages using filters.

from my log file -

```
2020-07-15 13:18:53.3291 ERROR MyAppName:MyAppName Some other error    
2020-07-15 13:18:53.3291 ERROR MyAppName:MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification.ProcessorControl Unknown : Unable to connect for notification control. 
2020-07-15 13:18:53.3291 ERROR MyAppName:MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification.ProcessorControl Exception Occurred in Unknown : AggregateException One or more errors occurred.
2020-07-15 13:18:53.3291 ERROR MyAppName:MyAppName Some other error
```

from Nlog.config file -

```xml
<target xsi:type="File"
        name="file"
        fileName="${var:basedir}/Logs/MyAppName-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} [${event-context:item=CC} ${event-context:item=Workstation} ${event-context:item=User} ${event-context:item=IL}] ${level:uppercase=true} ${logger} ${message} ${onexception: ${exception:format=shortType,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}}" >
</target>
    ...

<logger name="MyAppName:*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" >
      <filters>
        <when condition="contains('${message}','MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification')" action="Ignore" />
        <!--<when condition="contains('${message}','*MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification*')" action="Ignore" />-->
     </filters>
</logger>
```

I added filter to ignore any messages that may contain the string
"`MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification`" but it's not working.
I also tried with `*MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification*` as in the commented line - but my log file is still filled with these messages.
Can anyone please guide how can I fix this?

One more question -
Doesn't `$message` represents complete error message, like this from log file -

```
MyAppName:MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification.ProcessorControl Unknown : Unable to connect for notification control.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `MyAppName:MyAppName ` is in the ${message}? Please show the logger call and the target config

Comment: Hi Julian, thanks for your comment. updated my question with target rule. also added one question related to $message.

Comment: No `${message}` isn't the whole layout. I've added an answer with some explanation - hope it make some things clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification" is probably not in your `${message}`, but it's your logger name (`${logger}`)

#### `${message}`

When writing a log event, here are some example of `${message}`

- `logger.Info("My message");` -  `${message}` yields `"My message"`
- `logger.Info("Order {0}", 123);` -  `${message}` yields `"Order 123"`
- `logger.Info("Order {OrderId}", 123);` -  `${message}` yields `"Order 123"`. Structured style, read more [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging). In this case you have also `${event-properties:OrderId}` which yields `123`.
- Note: when using the  [ASP.NET Core integration](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3) , read `logger.LogInformation` instead of `logger.Info`

#### `${logger}`

The logger name, examples:

- `LogManager.GetLogger("logger1");` - `${logger}` yields `"logger1"`
- `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();` - `${logger}` yields something like `"MyClassNamespace.MyClass"`
- Injected `ILogger<MyClass>` - `${logger}` yields something like `"MyClassNamespace.MyClass"` - this in case you're using the ASP.NET Core integration.

#### Filtering

It's easy to filter on the logger name, it's built into the `<logger>` rule. The `name` attribute should be read as "filter on name" - `*` and `?` wildcards are supported.

Example:

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="MyAppName.BusinessLogic.*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="ErrorWithBusinessLogicStuffTarget" />
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#logger-name-filter)

### Notes

- When filtering the `final` attribute could be handy. For all options, see [here](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules)
- You could also use the `<when>` to filter with the `${logger}`, but that's harder to maintain and less performant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. You are right, the message I was filtering on is in ${logger}. Also, thank you for providing links for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing a rule so you have to wrap it around the `<rules></rules>` tag. and also use `name="*"` in place of `name="MyAppName:*"`.

Try the code below;

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file" >
          <filters>
            <when condition="contains('${message}','MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification')" action="Ignore" />
            <!--<when condition="contains('${message}','*MyAppName.BusinessLogic.Notification*')" action="Ignore" />-->
         </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

Comment: ooops. Alright, I edited again. use `name="*"` in place of `name="MyAppName:*"`.